# How to extract all keys and values from json? using Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have like this json.

```
{
  "a": 99,
  "b": "this, is, string",
  "c": "hi:"
}
```

I want to extract all keys and value to a array like this.
[image]

But `split(',')` is not working because there are multiple `,` in `"b": "this, is, string",`. Even I can't split using `:` because there's `:` in `hi:,`.

Could you give me some advice?

Comment: I'm sorry. I reverted it. And I will open another one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` with `.flat`:

```js
const fixedJson = `{
  "a": 99,
  "b": "this, is, string",
  "c": "hi:"
}`;

const obj = JSON.parse(fixedJson);

const result = Object.entries(obj).flat();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` to get seperated array with keys and values. Then you can merge these two arrays.

```js
const str = `{
  "a": 99,
  "b": "this, is, string",
  "c": "hi:"
}`;
const d = JSON.parse(str);
const k = Object.keys(d);
const v = Object.values(d);
const t = Math.min(k.length, v.length);

const m = [].concat(...Array.from({ length: t }, (_, i) => [k[i], v[i]]), k.slice(t), v.slice(t));
  
console.log('merged', m)
```